# post extra data with dropbox or start function

Tags: php

I have a simple dropdown menu which sends data to 'about.php'. Where in function it is processed and saved to databas. My question is how to post one more field which i fetched from the database on this page to next one? or to start a function with submit to use more than one field?
I googled for dropbox, but I get stuf from dropbox com....

```
 <form id="zend" action="about" method="post">
 <select id="clienten" name="toTheClient">
    <option value="">Select client</option><?php foreach ($clients as $c) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$c['client_id']?>"><?=$c['client_FN']?> 
            <?=$c['client_LN']?></option><?php } ?></select>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you would need to add a hidden field to the form:

```
<form id="zend" action="about.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="someExtra" value="valueFromDb">
 ...
```

Comment: ow.. so simple? :) i'll try it now.